# Akka-Http: How to TestProbe a request

Tags: scala, unit-testing, akka, akka-http

I have a request whose response depends on an actor reply. I am trying to test it in this way:

```
val myActor:TestProbe = TestProbe()

val route = new MyRoute() {
    override def myServiceActor:ActorRef = {
        myActor.ref
    }
}.route

"return a query result for GET" in {
    Get("/foo") ~> route ~> check {
        myActor.expectMsg(ExecuteFoo())
        myActor.reply(FOO)
        responseEntity shouldEqual toJsonEntity(RequestResult(FOO))
    }
}
```

I get correctly that `expectMsg` is verified but the `reply` is asynchronous respect to the `responseEntity` check. In this case the test fails.

Is there a way to wait for the reply?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're on the right track using a `TestProbe`.  The key is to separate the combination of running the request and then checking it (which you are doing as 1 step via `check`) into two explicit steps.  First run it, then do any stubbing on the `TestProbe` and lastly, make your checks.  The updated code for your sample would look like this:

```
  val result = Get("/foo") ~> route ~> runRoute
  myActor.expectMsg(ExecuteFoo())
  myActor.reply(FOO)

  check {
      responseEntity shouldEqual toJsonEntity(RequestResult(FOO))
  }(result)
```

You can see there that I'm first using `runRoute` to simple run the route without performing any checks.  I assign this value to `result` as I will need this later to perform any checks.  Then, you can safely do your stubbing against the `TestProbe`.  At this point, it's already received the message and is waiting for your calls to verify what message it got and how to respond.  Then, when done with that, we can call `check`, passing an explicit result (the one from `runRoute`) to that call instead of relying on an implicit.

If you follow this approach, you should be able to properly test routes that call an actor, using a `TestProbe` to do so.

Comment: like it! thank you! A sort of "yield" on the result makes rid of async problem :)

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this (which might not be the right one or the only one) is using `AutoPilot`. Here is an example:

```
val myProbe = TestProbe()
myProbe.setAutoPilot(new TestActor.AutoPilot {
  def run(sender: ActorRef, msg: Any) = msg match {
    case ExecuteFoo(_) =>
      //do something else if needed
      sender ! FOO
      TestActor.NoAutoPilot
  }
})
```

Comment: Interesting thank you. So far I tried just creating a mock with receive method and works fine. But I am not sure if it can introduce some intermitting test.